# equivalence class $[f]=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I consider the following  equivalence class

$$ [f]:= \{ g \in \mathcal{L} (\mu): f=g \text{ $\mu$-almost everywhere} \} $$

What does it mean, when $[f]=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $[f]=0$ means $[f]=[0]$.

Comment: Why can you leave the brackets out?

Comment: Perhaps there is the subtlety of observing that $[0]$ is the $0$ of the vector space; however, eventually the brackets stop being used once it's been established that it is always about classes of functions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.